# User-specific home page Django

Tags: python, django, url

I am trying to create a user-specific home page for my Django site (i.e., go directly to the logged-in user's page when the site is loaded).

I am having trouble figuring out how to add the username to the URL path from the get-go.

This is how I've typically created the path to the home page:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
```

But essentially what I think I want to do is this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('<username>/', include('blog.urls')),
```

So that the default home page when I run the server would be something like this :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/someusername
```

Is there a way to access the logged-in user by default automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

**In views.py:**

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def home(request):
    user_name = request.user.username
    return HttpResponseRedirect(f'{user_name}/')
```

**In urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('my_admin/admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',home),
    path('<str:username>/',include('blog.urls')),    
]
```